# A partir de quelles expressions connues sont composées ces phrases ?

Tags: expressions, proverbes

Pour ma licence de traductologie, je dois trouver les phraséologismes sur lesquels sont basées les phrases ci-dessous:

1. "bonne chasse et pêche et que la viande coule à flots"
2. "se faire prendre les pieds par tous les trous"

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut m'aider ?

---

Ces deux exemples sont les répliques du film "RRRrrrr" d'Alain Chabat. En contexte cela donne ça :

1. > A : C'est quoi cet accent ?
   >
   > B : C'est ma nouvelle langue, il me reste l'accent. Bonne chasse et pêche et que la viande coule à flots!
2. > A : Tous ses orifices ont été cousus.
   >
   > B : Tous ? Même ses doigts de pieds ?
   >
   > C : Les doigts de pieds, c’est pas un orifice…
   >
   > B : Ah oui ? Et pourquoi on dit s’faire prendre les pieds par tous les trous ?
   >
   > C : On dit pas ça.

Comment: Si tu explicitais un peu le terme *phraséologie*, on pourrait probablement outrepasser la perplexité (l'hilarité ? l'écoeurement ?) qui se dégage de la première lecture et essayer une réponse constructive. Qu'en dis-tu ?

Comment: houla... moi la 2) me fait penser étrangement à une citation du père noël est une ordure à propos de Thèrese :-)

Comment: Basiquement, je dirais que ces expressions sont fautives et qu'il faut retrouver les bonnes. Pour la première, on voit bien l'expression "couler à flots" qui ne marche pas pour la viande (expression réservée au vin) il s'agit de la remplacer.

Comment: @mansuetus: dire qu'elles sont fautives est ambigu, dans la mesure où ce sont des expressions qui ont mises dans le film pour faire rire. Elles figurent toutes les deux dans le film [RRRrrrr!!!](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRRrrrr!!!), on peut donc dire que ce sont des créations littéraires. Je n'ai pas de réponses complètes, je vois « l'argent coule à flots », « se prendre les pieds dans le tapis » qui pourrait s'entremêler avec « se faire pendre par les pieds »...

Answer (score 8):

Si je comprends bien la question, il faut retrouver derrière ces phrases des expressions plus classiques (ces deux exemples sont complètement artificiels et ne peuvent se trouver que dans un contexte de comédie où on détourne des expressions existantes).

1. Dans la première, comme dit en commentaire, on dit "le vin coule à flot" dans des circonstances où il y a beaucoup de vin à boire et où les convives ne se privent pas d'en profiter. Le comique de la phrase vient du fait que la viande bien sûr ne coule pas, mais on comprend quand même que celui qui parle souhaite aux autres de rapporter de la viande en abondance.
2. Dans la deuxième il y a un mélange. "Se prendre les pieds" dans quelque chose (souvent un tapis par exemple) signifie trébucher dessus. "Se faire prendre par tous les trous" est à éviter en bonne société et a à voir avec l'utilisation de tous les orifices du corps humain à des fins sexuelles.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la première, je vois :

1. [bonne pêche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%EAche), cf. 4.a, le bon résultat d’une activité de pêche;
2. Chasse et Pêche, était une émission de télévision de nuit sur TF1 dans les années 90 consacrée aux sujets — [une chaîne de télévision a repris le nom](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasse_et_P%EAche);
3. [couler à flots](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flot), cf. 5, où à flots signifie en abondance.

Dans la seconde, pas mieux que Ri49.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une *phraséologie* (phraséologisme est un néologisme) de *réplique comique* (Cf. : la réponse de Ri49) qui tire son humour de la distorsion apportée à une expression très usité par un remplacement inattendu d'un élément du texte.

Comment: Tu souhaites dire par là que les expressions originales sont comiques ? Ce n'est pas vrai.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Non ! Les expressions originales sont souvent des proverbes ou des formules du langage courant, parfois sentencieuses. Ce qui les rend humoristique, c'est le remplacement d'un assertion par une autre (avec souvent un sous-entendu grivois). La construction sémantique de la phrase, (appelée ici phraséologie, objet de la question) repose sur cette substitution.

Comment: Certes, *phraséologisme* est un néologisme, mais c’est un néologisme apparemment utilisé dans son domaine et qui a apparemment — mais je n’en suis pas sûr, je n’arrive pas à trouver de définition claire — est bien distinct de *phraséologie*.

Comment: @Édouard PHRASEOLOGIE : Ensemble des expressions (terminologie et particularités syntaxiques) propres à un usage, à un milieu, à une époque, à un écrivain ; Un ISME est un concept, le plus souvent idéologique, dont le nom se termine par le suffixe -isme ;  HERMENEUTIQUE :  qui a pour objet l'interprétation des texte ==> Phraséologisme == herméneutique des phraséologies ? [Le Robert & Wikipédia]